# Nuxtjs in index.js SyntaxError

Tags: nuxt.js

**SyntaxError
Unexpected token o in JSON at position 1**

import cookieparser from 'cookieparser'

export const actions = {
nuxtServerInit({ commit }, { req }) {

```
  if (req && req.headers && req.headers.cookie){
    const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)

    if (parsed.userjwt == 'null')
    commit('auth/setUser', null)
    else 
    commit('auth/setUser', parsed.userjwt)
  }
  /* parse cart */

  let cart
  if (req && req.headers && req.headers.cookie) {
    const parsed = cookieparser.parse(req.headers.cookie)
    cart = (parsed.cart && JSON.parse(parsed.cart)) || []
 
  }

  commit('cart/setItems', cart)

  /* parse cart */
```

},
}

Comment: Are you sure your backend is sending you something correct? This is usually the cause.